# CAPTCHA does not look like the way it should in my contact form in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, captcha, recaptcha

I'm new to Joomla and recently I've tried a lot to enable captcha for my contact forms and I've done all the steps to do it. (enabling captcha in Plugins,global configuration and user manager) but after all I just see this in my form:
*Security Code(Captcha)
and the code itself and the textfield to enter the captcha code are not displayed.
what should I do??? As I said I'm new to Joomla please explain step by step. By the way my site's language is Persian(Although it is not important)
this is how my form looks like after enabling captcha:
[My form after enabling CAPTCHA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMIX9.png)

Comment: No code, no help. We cannot help fix problems based on pictures of problems.

Comment: This is not done by code, at least I know this way, and if it's done by code then give me a piece of code.

Comment: Then you've come to the WRONG place. this site is for programming questions. we are not general software tech support.

Comment: What am I doing??? I'm just doing what you call programming. but I've got stuck in a part of it where I don't know whether it's done by changing some options or using a piece of code. If you don't know the answer just read and go. There is no need for showing up.

Comment: "not done by code", therefore it's not programming. you're just USING joomla, not actually writing code within joomla

Comment: Whatever. You don't know the answer.

Comment: how could I? You've shown NOTHING of what the code building that page looks like, or the code inserting the captcha. we are not mind readers, we have NO idea what you're doing. "but I clicked around and followed some random guide I found on the interwebitubez" is NOT useful information.

Comment: Marc B check the answer. Is it code or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 24 hours of searching on the net finally I found the answer.
Under the site's Home directory You must go to:
public_html -> plugins -> captcha -> recaptcha
and open the file named recaptcha.php.
Search for the pieces of code mentioned bellow and make the following changes:

**change**

```
const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://api.recaptcha.net";
const RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "api-verify.recaptcha.net";
```

**To**

```
const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
const RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "www.google.com";
```

**and also change**

```
$response = $this->_recaptcha_http_post(self::RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER, "/verify"
```

**To**

```
$response = $this->_recaptcha_http_post(self::RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER, "/recaptcha/api/verify"
```

Then save and reload your page. it's done.
Don't forget that this is needed in Joomla 2.5 where the version of RECAPTCHA is 1.0 if your Joomla is a newer version you don't need to change anything just enable RECAPTCHA.